# How to prevent Laptop from sleep when it hits critical battery

Tags: gnome, power-management, battery

I have Pop_OS 21.04 installed on my laptop. Sometimes the laptop suddenly drops to 0% even through it could run for hours more. The issue is that the power manager triggers sleep, even through I changed its configuration in the gnome-power-manager settings using dconf at:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/
```

The changes are:

`percentage-action/percentage-critical` set to -1

`critical-battery-action` set to nothing

`use-time-for-policy` set to false

Any idea why the gnome power manager is ignoring these settings?

Comment: Either buy a new original battery or remove battery power-management from your Linux (not recommend).

Comment: What about the question, why is gnome power manager ignoring these settings?

Comment: It's a safety measure to prevent data loss. Your battery is old, get a replacement. You may only deactivate this safety measure by deactivating the battery power-management, which is not recommend.

Comment: My laptop battery controller is dumb, sometimes when the battery reaches ~50% it immediately shows 0%, even through I am able to force it to run for multiple hours more while it is showing 0%. The battery is not that old, only about 2.5 years old.

Comment: Batteries old faster when used incorrectly. For example having often the power charger attached, even when not needed.

Comment: I don't leave my laptop plugged all the time, and my battery remaining capacity reported is 88%, so it is still pretty good, it is just this dumb circuit that counts battery percentage that may go insane sometimes and I want this to stop interrupting me. This is Linux, there should be nothing that can't be changed. I just want gnome-power-manager to do nothing on critical battery, and I understand the risk of it. @paladin

Comment: seeking more configuration options, maybe see about maybe having configuration files like UPower.conf mentioned by the question and answers in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088237/hibernate-suspend-on-critical-battery-level-where-should-i-set-it-from-mate-gu

Comment: Back when I tried 2 years ago, it seems that UPower is too stubborn and will always try to shutdown the device. So disabling it is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid critical action by completely stopping upower:

`sudo systemctl stop upower && sudo systemctl mask --runtime upower`

Don't do it unless you understand the risks involved in overriding power management.